# Http post Request in Service?

Tags: android, service, http-post, httprequest

I have wallpaper service i wrote an Http post request code in the service (new thread) but  I can't get result from it I test my url on postman (chrome) and other thing i can get the responce but here I cant even know if it's working please help and take a look at my code ( please help me to read the responce on toast or system out or .....)

This is my http post request.

```
  public static String HttpParoonakRequestGetUrl(){

    URL url ;
        HttpURLConnection client = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("my url");

        client = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        client.setRequestMethod("POST");

        client.setRequestProperty("method","get_random_wallpaper");


        client.setUseCaches (false);
        client.setDoInput(true);
        client.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
                client.getOutputStream ());
        wr.flush ();
        wr.close ();

        //Get Response
        InputStream is = client.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
            response.append('\n');

        }
        rd.close();
        Log.d("hey",response.toString());

        return response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
                        e.getMessage();
        return null;


         }
    finally {
        if(client != null) // Make sure the connection is not null.
            client.disconnect();
    }

}
```

my service

```
public class MainActivity extends WallpaperService {






@Override
public Engine onCreateEngine() {
    return new WallpaperEngine();
}

class WallpaperEngine extends Engine {
    //Duration between slides in milliseconds
    private final int SLIDE_DURATION = 2000;

    private int[] mImagesArray;
    private int mImagesArrayIndex = 0;
    private Thread mDrawWallpaper,thread;


    public WallpaperEngine() {



        mImagesArray = new int[] {R.drawable.garden1,R.drawable.garden2,R.drawable.garden3,R.drawable.garden4,R.drawable.girl1,
                R.drawable.girl2,R.drawable.greenww,R.drawable.sports1,R.drawable.sports2,R.drawable.sports3,R.drawable.sports4};

        mDrawWallpaper = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (true) {

                        drawFrame();
                        incrementCounter();
                        Thread.sleep(SLIDE_DURATION);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                    e.getMessage();
                }


            }
        });


        thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String a = HttpParoonakRequest.HttpParoonakRequestGetUrl();
                    System.out.println("Message1 "+ a);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),a,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                    e.getMessage();
                }

            }
        });
        thread.start();
        mDrawWallpaper.start();


    }





    private void incrementCounter() {
        mImagesArrayIndex++;

        if (mImagesArrayIndex >= mImagesArray.length) {
            mImagesArrayIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    private void drawFrame() {
        final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();

        Canvas canvas = null;

        try {
            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();

            if (canvas != null) {
                drawImage(canvas);
            }
        } finally {
            if (canvas != null) {
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }

    private void drawImage(Canvas canvas)
    {

        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                mImagesArray[mImagesArrayIndex]);
        Bitmap b=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), true);
        canvas.drawBitmap(b, 0,0, null);
    }




}
```

and of course I use permission internet in the manifest

Comment: anyone?...........

Comment: You are not posting anything to begin with. You only open and close a stream.

Comment: `response.toString();`. That is the response. What is wrong with it?

Comment: `HttpParoonakRequest.execute();`??? How can we know what this call will do without seeing code?

Comment: `class MainActivity extends WallpaperService`. How terrible to call a Service an Activity.

Comment: my mainactivity isn't a activity it is a class my main activitys name is main

Comment: response.toString will give me the body of the php ? on log cat ?? or textview

Comment: execute is wrong sry its HttpParoonakRequestGetUrl i updated my code

Comment: `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),a,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`. You cannot use aToast() in the run() of a Thread. It will crash your app. Look in the LogCat.

Comment: `response.toString will give me the body of the php ? on log cat ?? or textview`. Yes that should be what php returns. Now what do you get? Tell us! You can use it where you want of course. That's up to you. There must be some reason why you call that php script isn't it ?

Comment: i dont have any response actually i dont know if i get one :(

Comment: its just a string in the body of the post

Comment: You should put a Log.d() statement there that prints response.toString(). Then you will know. Tell us.

Comment: i putted like this  and nothing appears 
Log.d("hey",response.toString());

Comment: `catch (Exception e)`. If you have an exception you dont know ots cause. Put a `return e.getMessage()` in every catch block.. And you have already ` System.out.println("Message1 "+ a);`. So why do you not report what its prints?

Comment: `i putted like this and nothing appears`. Ok. But where did you put it? Please adapt your code so we can see. Also put Log.d() statements in that catch block. You will stay blind if you don't. And tell what ` System.out.println("Message1 "+ a);` prints.

Comment: that system out prints just message 1

Comment: ` message 1` ????? Impossible! Cant you be more presice? And do you realise that `a` can be `null` . It will be null when there was a catch!. You should check for that.

Comment: i updated my code like u say take a look and yea if i search on message word it appears just message1 and 2 under each other without a

Comment: this body should be response i guess
{"result": "PA763Gyy6h2XxIwvA5E1",
                      "errorMessage": "error"}

Comment: `i updated my code like u say `. No. You tried. But Log.d(response.toString()) should be below the while loop. Before the return.. And there still is no return statement in the catch block.

Comment: `response.append('\r');`. That should be `response.append('\n');`.

Comment: It is time you show your php script.

Comment: there is catch return null

Comment: do u want my server url ?

Comment: Do you think i do not see that? But i asked you to put `return e.getMessage()` in the catch block. Why do you refuse?

Comment: First tell if it is indeed php. Why are you answering so NON to the point?

Comment: dude i'm putting it  now i update the code

Comment: yea its php 
my menthor said to me to post request it and need to see that connected with each other

Comment: check the code again please

Comment: `return null;` My god why did you put that in that catch block? I told you what you had to put there twice! Reread my comments!

Comment: You did not post a php script.

Comment: how i can do it i have no idea i have just the url

Comment: Adapt your code here so we can see what you do. Then report what the Log.d() and System.println() statements print.

Comment: log.d didn't give me anything
sys.out.print gives me message 1 and message 2 
of course all of this when i press the button

Comment: I can only wait untill you put the requested returns in those catch blocks.

Comment: `sys.out.print gives me message 1 and message 2` ??? You are not precise! Why are you too lazy to report decently. It will me `Message1`. And you use `System.out.` not `sys.out`.

Comment: it system.out bro i just  commented like that and i changed inside all the catch :O

Comment: with debug i get response " "